# Router dies on wifi usage

Tags: router, wifi, netgear

We're having a Netgear WGR614v2 router, and as soon as a device generates some WiFi Traffic, the router completely dies.

By opening http://9gag.com/ I can reproduce the problem.

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=215 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Is it possible that the router can't handle the number of simultanious connections that modern browsers use?

It's quite old.

There's probably nothing you can do?

Comment: Such are the risks of connecting museum pieces to the modern network.

Comment: This comment is in no way answering my question! So this is a possible reason?

Comment: In firefox I set _network.http.max-connections_ to 2 (from 256), which solves the problem. So my guess is that the number of connections IS the reason. But already 10 crashes it again, which is like nothing and seems unlikely.

Comment: There's probably nothing you can do. Some of those old routers (and even some new ones!) were very bad at handling simultaneous connections.

Comment: Most likely it's a hardware issue (usually power supply goes bad because of dried electrolitic capacitors), does no longer supply regulated voltage, and changes in power draw will cause voltage drops.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same model (or same family) long time ago and it had similar symptoms before it completely died. Network traffic slowed down, and WiFi range dropped dramatically. When opened, I noticed some of the capacitors had noticeable 'bulges'.

So I'm guessing the electronics inside yours is just coming to the end of its life.

Comment: thx, Maybe that's it, I'll take a look inside when I'm back.